# Bottle: HEAD always falls back to GET, thus functions always executed twice?

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I'm using [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org) to implement a web interface for a simple database system. [As documented](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#http-request-methods), Bottle handles HTTP HEAD requests by falling back to the corresponding GET route and cutting off the response body. However, in my experience, it means that the function attached to the GET route is executed *both times* in response to a GET request. This can be problematic if that function performs an operation that side-effects, such as a database operation.

Is there a way to prevent this double execution from happening?  Or should I define a fake HEAD route for every GET route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: It sounds like Bottle is working as designed (calling the function only once per request). Your browser is the apparent source of the `HEAD` requests.

---

On HEAD requests, Bottle calls the method once, not twice. Can you demonstrate some code that shows the behaviour you're describing? When I run the following code, I see the "Called" line only once:

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()

@app.get("/")
def home():
    print(f"Called: {request.method}")
    return "Some text\n"

app.run()
```

Output:

```
$ curl --head http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Called: HEAD
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2021 08:28:02] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2021 13:28:02 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.6
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear test case. This helped clarify what is happening: I see a GET followed by a HEAD when I refresh the window on the page (in Safari on macOS 10.13.6) but not on the first visit to the page. The first visit only generates a GET, which is what I (perhaps naively) expected in both cases. There must be something I don't understand about browser behavior in the two cases.

Comment: Also, I tried to clarify my question that this is about GET, not HEAD.

Comment: Correct, your browser is (for whatever reason) issuing two requests, a `GET` and a `HEAD`. As designed, Bottle will only call your method once for every incoming request.

Comment: Also: you should use `curl` (or `wget`, etc) to test your app. A browser is fine, but when there's unexpected behaviour, the best way to see what's happening is to use the command line (and/or use Safari developer tools to see the requests being made).

Comment: I've identified the source of the problem: it is a browser extension. Turning off extensions results in refreshes only issuing a single GET. It's not browser-specific, either, because it happens in Chrome (where I also have a lot of extensions). So, Bottle is not doing something unexpected; however, I still need to guard against this situation (i.e., multiple requests) in my app – after all, real-world users may have browser extensions that cause this.

Comment: Since this is a behavior that any app developer will face with any framework, I think I should ask a separate question about it.

Comment: Great, makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: "I still need to guard against this situation" - I don't get the situation you're worried about. Can't your service legitimately be called twice? If you just want to short-circuit `HEAD` requests, you could always return from your function early if `request.method == "HEAD"`. (Though I would try to make `HEAD` report the same `content-length` that `GET` would have.)

Comment: Re calling twice: for pages that only display information, yes. But the app has REST API endpoints too. During simple testing with a browser, I was seeing those endpoints get called twice because i was doing simple tests using a browser. I misattributed this to something Bottle was doing, and assumed it would always happen. The fundamental mistake was testing with a browser instead of `curl` or `wget`, getting bad data as a result, and drawing incorrect conclusions. And now having talked through all this, I realize I _don't_ actually need to ask another question :-).